# Куда пишет обработчик RegisterModuleDependences?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, битрикс

В битриксе есть обработчик, который я хочу использовать для сбора отчетов:

```
RegisterModuleDependences("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", "OnWeekAfterReviewAdded");
```

При отправке сообщений он должен писать в базу а потом выводить определенный промежуток. По сути отчет годовой, месячный, недельный. Однако не понятно, куда пишет эти события данный хук. К сожалению не нашел этого в документации.
..
Есть сообщения о отзыве формируемые массивом:

```
AddEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementAdd", "OnWeekAfterReviewAdded");

function OnWeekAfterReviewAdded($arFields)
{
    if($arFields['IBLOCK_ID'] == IBLOCK_REVIEWS_ID)
    {
        $arEventFields = array(
            'LINK_TO_REVIEW' => $arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES']['LINK'],
            'TEXT'           => $arFields['DETAIL_TEXT'],
            'NAME'           => $arFields['NAME'],
            'DATE'           => $arFields['DATE_ACTIVE_FROM'],
            'IP'           => $arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES']['IP'],
            'EMAIL'           => $arFields['PROPERTY_VALUES']['EMAIL'],
            'ID' => $arFields['IBLOCK_ID'],
            'TEST' => $arFields,
        );
        CEvent::Send('EMAIL_WEEK_REPORT', 's1', $arEventFields);
    } 
}
```

Мне же необходимо это событие отправлять в раз в месяц первого числа и в понедельник.

Comment: вроде бы это хук для связи модулей: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/module/registermoduledependences.php вам же нужны cron-задачи, либо агенты. напишите подробнее, что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ссылка на документацию [RegisterModuleDependences](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/module/registermoduledependences.php). Как следует из названия Эта функция регистрирует зависимости модуля. Ее стоит использовать когда вы разрабатываете свой модуль для битрикса.

По сути вызов этого метода создает запись в таблице `b_module_to_module`.

Скорее всего вам нужен метод [AddEventHandler](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/module/addeventhandler.php), который регистрирует обработчик события на лету (без записи в базу данных).

Разница этих подходов:

- RegisterModuleDependences - вызывается 1 раз за время работы проекта, например при установке модуля. Обработчик регистрируется в базе с указанием модуля, в котором определен обработчик. Срабатывание события, приведет к подключению модуля.
- AddEventHandler - исполняется на каждом хите, дополняет массив обработчиков собранных из базы.

Используемый вами обработчик [OnAfterIBlockElementAdd](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/events/onafteriblockelementadd.php) срабатывает на каждом изменении элемента инфоблока, но не гарантируется его вызов при изменении свойств.

Если вы хотите собирать факт изменений элементов инфоблоков, это можно сделать на странице настроек инфоблока, вкладка "Журнал событий"

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне нужно писать в базу и делать выборки для отправки.

Comment: Но битрикс себя позиционирует, как: "Новичкам надо поклясться на мануале, что они забудут про прямые запросы, вообще про БД забудут. Когда появится немного опыта и будет казаться что вы зверь в Битриксе - тогда можно почитать о том как происходит общение с БД, но все равно не трогать, подождать еще год-два активной работы с системой. И вот только потом уже можно подружиться с БД полностью, но помнить, что в первую очередь надо всеми правдами и неправдами сделать стандартными методами Битрикс. К БД прибегать только в случае:"

Comment: Мне до успеха не хватает знаний, как писать через создать, писать с базу данных.

Comment: > как писать через создать

Не понял о чем речь.